# Intel x520 SFP+ connecting to a J9264A HP Procure 6600 switch

Tags: hp-procurve, sfp, 10gbase

I have an Intel h2000 4 module (s2000WP mobi's) chassis with 2 port (Chipset 82599 x520 sfp+ card in each module.

I was wanting to buy/use a J9264A HP 6600 procurve 24+4 that has 4 SFP+ 10GBE ports.

I have bought HP X242 10G SFP+ to SFP+ 3m DAC Cable J9283B DAC cables that are happily compatable with the procurve 6600 switch

I was told the intel x520 should also connect to nearly anything and all should be well does this sound right ??

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel cards are usually agnostic when it comes to SFPs in my experience, but DAC-cables are a bit of a grey area since there's no standard governing them if I can remember correctly. So if you want to play it safe, buy some 3rd party SFPs for the HP swiches and the name-brand modules for Intel (the Intel modules are cheap enough, but name brand HP modules cost hundreds of dollars per module) and run the whole lot over OM3 fiber instead, it's every so slightly more expensive as the DAC cables. Also, if you haven't bought the X520 cards yet, they can be had with or without SFPs of your choice for the same price.